# The npm puppeter package is returning an error regarding node_package space

Tags: javascript, node.js, apify

Here is the error that it is returning

[Here is a picture of the error i'm getting when I run npm install puppeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVHb5.png)

I found some stuff online with permissions, but this is about node_package space. It is not disk space as I've looked over my disk storage availability and there's plenty. Working on an Apify SDK, and I'm following the documentation, but the console is returning a whole bunch of error messages.

Can someone please help?

```html
const Apify = require('apify')

Apify.main(async () => {
    const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();
    await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: 'https://www.iana.org/' });

    const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
        requestQueue,
        handlePageFunction: async ({ request, page }) => {
            const title = await page.title();
            console.log(`Title of ${request.url}: ${title}`);
            await Apify.utils.enqueueLinks({
               requestQueue,
               page,
               pseudoUrls: ['https://www.iana.org/[.*]'],
            });
        },
    });

    await crawler.run();
});
```

Comment: This is not a code issue, it most likely is a setup issue. Can you provide some detail on how you're setting up your project? e.g. where the `/Users/` path is how are you mapping your drives etc?

Comment: The project is located in my documents directory and is running with nodemon

Comment: it's in my local directory

Comment: Is it possible there is insufficient space left on another partition? Puppeteer automatically downloads and installs a browser to the main system partition.

Comment: I solved the problem. Don't ask me how because I don't know. I force quit the application, came back in a few hours, and it suddenly worked.